# How can I call programs that are already running to open new files from Perl or a bash script?

Tags: linux, perl

I am using a Perl script to find data needed to deal with errors from another process. In OSX, these lines in the Perl script open the needed sites and files in my browser and text editor. Here's the code that works in OSX:

```
 if ($^O eq "darwin") {
      system `open -a /Applications/Firefox.app https://site`;
      system `open -a /Apopen -a /Applications/Komodo.appplications/Komodo.app file1.md file2.md`;
      system `open -a /Applications/Komodo.app file3.md`;}
```

I can run this script repeatedly and the apps will add tabs with the new open files.

However, I will need to run the same tool on Linux, and I haven't found any way to do it. Here's how I've tried to adapt it to Linux.

```
 if ($^O eq "linux") {
      system `firefox local_file.html & disown`;
      system `firefox https://site1 https://sitex & disown`;
      system `komodo  file1 file2 filex & disown`;
      }
```

I have since adjusted the Perl script so that it outputs a shell that I can run from the command line (latest version as per suggestion by @Grant McLean):

```
xdg-open https://www.site1 & disown
xdg-open https://www.site2 & disown
xdg-open /home/.../file1.html & disown
xdg-open /home/.../file2.md & disown
xdg-open /home/.../file3.md & disown
```

I gather from @Grant McLean's suggestion that if I were to integrate it into the Perl script the lines would be, e.g.,

```
system "xdg-open { file | site } & disown";
```

But since the shell hangs the system, I'm assuming that passing the commands to the system from the Perl script would also hang the system.

I want to be able to have the browser and the text editor open files from a shell and not have to open files individually in each app. Any ideas?

Comment: is the missing space before https deliberate?

Comment: The fact that your code uses both `system` and backticks is a little odd. The `system` function will run a command, the backtick quotes will also run a command, capture the output and return it. Usually you'd use one or the other. Maybe you want `system "xdg-open https://site /Users/.../File2.html"` for the browser one.

Comment: @jhnc No, I typed instead of copied and mis-typed it. I've fixed the error now. Thanks.

Comment: @Abigail, thanks for responding. Those are the only lines of the Perl script that access the system.

Comment: Thank you, @Abigail. I've edited to add code.

Comment: Thank you, @GrantMcLean. I've edited the OP to deal with your suggestion.

Comment: You're still using both backticks and `system`. Why?

Comment: @melpomene, my ignorance, I guess. The OSX version works as is, so I never questioned it. Once I can get a Linux shell script that opens the programs and doesn't hang the system, I'll put the relevant commands into a `system` command in the Perl script and use quote marks. Thanks for the reminder :-) .

Comment: @Abigail, you're absolutely right.
How can I repeatedly feed small bits of error data generated by my heuristic Perl script (which works in Linux) into a shell or Perl command to find the files that contain data needed to correct the errors, and display them in a text editor and browser?
Opening each file or site individually is time consuming.
The Perl script that finds the needed files works fine in Linux. But I can't find a way to open them using a shell (or a system call from Perl) that doesn't hang the system.
What is the Linux equivalent (or workaround) of the OSX procedure? Thanks!

Comment: @Abigail, thanks for sticking with this. Only changing backticks to quotes:
`system "firefox https://site1 &";
system "firefox https://site2 https://site3 &";
system "komodo file1 file2 &";
system "komodo file3 &";`
The second instance of Firefox yields an error "Firefox is already open" and doesn't open the file. I'm assuming running the script with different data that would lead me to file4, file5, site4, site5, etc., would hang the system. (Putting `disown` after `&` hung so thoroughly I needed to turn the machine off.)

Comment: @Abigail, thanks for all your help. I'm not sure whether I don't have the Linux background needed to implement your solution or if I'm trying to do the impossible. I'll try getting in line for the in-house guru, and if he gives me a solution I'll get back to you (probably after a few days) to let you know what he came up with. Again, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Abigail thanks again for your help. I got some live help and I think I'm set now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a variation of what @grantmclean suggested. His solution didn't work when I tried it because I was trying to `xdg-open` more than one file or site at a time. Opening one at a time works:

```
if ($^O eq "linux") {
    system "xdg-open https://site1 &";
    system "xdg-open https://site2 &";
    my @tWs = split / /,$tW_files;
    foreach (@tWs) {
        system "xdg-open $_ &" # opens a series of local files
    }
    system "xdg-open file_y &";
    system "xdg-open file_z &";
}
```

My thanks to you all!